# How to use image Url in gofpdf

Tags: go

i am using golang in service side, i am create a pdf using gofpdf , i need to show image on the top of the pdf page, in gofpdf documentation they provide a methods for this ImageOptions(), Image() i have image link URL i will do like below but it's not working ,got error file not found.

```
ImageOptions(https://cdn.recast.ai/newsletter/city-01.png, 10, 10, 30, 
 0, false, "", 0, "")
```

And

```
Image(https://cdn.recast.ai/newsletter/city-01.png,10, 10, 30, 0, false, "", 0, "")
```

Above both are not working,Any one help me how to show image using image Url.
Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess: both functions take a filename as an argument, not a URL.

Comment: @peter is right. When you take a look at gopdf's github page, there is an image example, using a local image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got a solution for this it's woks me, if you want to show image on your pdf , first you need to register your image (it do inside http.get() call to your image), I hope this below  link is useful.

```
url := "https://cdn.recast.ai/newsletter/city-01.png"
httpimg.Register(pdf, url, "")
pdf.Image(url, 15, 15, 267, 0, false, "", 0, "")
```

Reference link:
https://godoc.org/github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/contrib/httpimg

Comment: Be carefull using an empty `tp` parameter on production environments. This was breaking our code on production. If you get this error, you can fix it by adding an explicit `tp` parameter according to the image MIME Type that you are using.
Example: `httpimg.Register(pdf, url, "png")`.

`tp` values comes from ImageTypeFromMime (https://github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/blob/master/fpdf.go)